# Sending multiple params through selector?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parameters, selector

I want to use a selector to get to my controller and pass 2 values, the sender and a number.

Issue is that i get the crash:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CDCFaderController changeView:]: unrecognised selector sent to instance 0x109db6f40'

The code makes sense to me so not sure why, anyone able to help?

```
[self.viewController performSelector:@selector(changeView:) withObject:self withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: channel.channelNumber]];
```

Receiver:

```
- (void)changeView:(UIButton *)sender chanToPush:(NSNumber*)channel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selector is wrong. `@selector(changeView:)` should be this `@selector(changeView:chanToPush:)`.

Try this.

```
[self.viewController performSelector:@selector(changeView:chanToPush:) withObject:self withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: channel.channelNumber]];
```

Comment: thanks this worked, i didnt realise i had to add the param to the func name when the sender wasnt already included either

Comment: In Objective-C the function name does double-duty as the external name of the first parameter (if there is one.)

Answer (score 0):

**Use as this**

```
[self performSelector:@selector(changeView:chanToPush:) withObject:self withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: channel.channelNumber]];

- (void)changeView:(UIButton *)sender chanToPush:(NSNumber*)channel
{
    NSLog(@"channel is --%@",channel);
}
```

**OR**

```
[self performSelector:@selector(changeView:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: channel.channelNumber]];

- (void) changeView:(NSNumber *)num
{ //
}
```